# Windows network shared folder vlc player can't see

Tags: windows, networking, vlc-media-player, shared-folders, sharing

i am using windows 11 home the latest 22h version. I share a folder and use VLC on my TV to play local content from my computer.

VCL never sees the shared folder. But when i disable/enable ethernet adapter on my pc, then it sees it. I have to do this everytime after a reboot. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Update / replace the network driver and restart.  NET USE Z: \\computer\folder  .   Any errors?

Comment: What is your ethernet adapter?

Comment: @John i am not sure how to use that command. my shared folder is F:\Shared

Comment: Use Device Manager to update the driver and see if that helps.

Comment: @harrymc its Intel(R) Ethemet Controller (3) 1225-V #2

Comment: @John did that, didn't help, looks like some service isn't starting maybe? since when i disable and enable, the share is seen from VLC and it remains like that for some hours, even when i restart, then suddenly it doesn't show again, and i have to disable and enable

Comment: Then there seems to be some issue with the operating system causing this issue.   Try DISM / SFC  .....    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Try installing the [Intel Network Adapter Driver for Windows 10](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/18293/intel-network-adapter-driver-for-windows-10.html).

Comment: @John i did everything you said in order and it said no corruption or anything were found as such except when i did SFC /SCANNOW this is what i got
.
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.

Do i need to worry about this?

Comment: I provided a fairly comprehensive answer for you. It should work

Comment: Do we know this is a server side issue, or could the problem be with DNS or the VLC client?

Comment: @music2myear i dont know, i am still not able to fix this, the only way to get VLC to see it again is to disable and re enable the ethernet adapter, tried everything said above, to me, it seems like some service isn't running by default